# how to show image in yajra datatable column , laravel5.3

Tags: laravel-5, yajra-datatable

i am adding a column in datatable for image like this :

```
->addColumn('product_brand_logo', function ($product_brand) {
    return '<img src="{{ URL::to('upload/image')'.$img->image.'" border="0" width="40" class="img-rounded" align="center" />';
```

its not working the output in inspect

```
| {{ URL::to('upload/image')imagename.png}}|
```

using **laravel 5.3**, **yajra datatable 6.0**

Comment: Where did you do `->addColumn ....` ??

Comment: here is tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pPvD7xwCq4&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 10):

If you are using **datatable 7.0**

Then you can use **[rawColumns](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/raw-columns)**

> In cases where you want to render an html content, please use rawColumns api

```
return DataTables::of($artists)->addColumn('image', function ($artist) {
    $url= asset('storage/'.$artist->image);
    return '<img src="'.$url.'" border="0" width="40" class="img-rounded" align="center" />';
})->addColumn('action', function ($artist) {
    return '<a href="/admin/artist/'.$artist->id.'/edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a>
    <a href="admin/artist/"'.$artist->id .'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';
})->rawColumns(['image', 'action'])->make(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't close `{{` in `src` attribute, try this :

```
->addColumn('product_brand_logo', function ($product_brand) { 
       $url=asset("uploads/image/$product_brand->image"); 
       return '<img src='.$url.' border="0" width="40" class="img-rounded" align="center" />'; 
});
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'upload' (T_STRING), expecting ';'

Comment: Try the updated answer, there is no need to use blade syntax :)

Comment: i try but i got error  from datatable   `DataTables warning: table id=users-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

Comment: Ithink it's `$product_brand->image` not `$img->image` ??

Comment: @user7647067 what do you think ??

Comment: this code i am adding in my datatable for showing recored, i am using yajra datatables 6.0

Comment: try this `->addColumn('product_brand_logo', function ($product_brand) {
    return '<img src="'.URL::to('upload/image').$product_brand->image.'" border="0" width="40" class="img-rounded" align="center" />';
`

Comment: same error i got ` DataTables warning: table id=users-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

Comment: problem solved this is my code i hope it help any one else `->addColumn('product_brand_logo', function ($product_brand) {
              $url=asset("uploads/image/$product_brand->image");
            return '<img src='.$url.' border="0" width="40" class="img-rounded" align="center" />';
        });`

Comment: I edited my answer with your code to help other people to find it, because lot of them don't see the comments :)

Answer (score 4):

To Display image in DataTable, we need to use render function on the column to display images. You can define your own render function. In our case, we want to render an image, something like following,

```
render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return "<img src=\"/path/" + data + "\" height=\"50\"/>";
        }
```

overall look like this -

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( '#users-table' ).DataTable( {
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{!! route('route_name') !!}",
            columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                { data: 'avatar', name: 'avatar',
                    render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
                        return "<img src=\"/path/" + data + "\" height=\"50\"/>";
                    }
                },
                { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same problem... and it was solved with the following code in my `UserController`.

In my example, I don´t save the image in the DB, only the name of the image to access with the image name stored in my project...

Nice.. it works

`->addColumn('image', function ($user) { $url=asset("uploads/image/$user->avatar"); 
return '<img src='.$url.' border="0" width="40" class="img-rounded" align="center" />'; });`

Answer (score 1):

```
->addColumn('product_brand_logo', function ($product_brand) {
        return '<img src="{{ asset('upload/image/')'.$img->image.'" border="0" 
        width="40" class="img-rounded" align="center" />';
})->rawColumns(['product_brand_logo', 'action']);
```

**Just call"->rawColumns(['product_brand_logo', 'action'])" after edit/add column**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following code

```
          {data: 'logo', name: 'logo',
            render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return "<img src=\"/images/clients/" + data + "\" height=\"150\" 
                alt='No Image'/>";
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This will do the trick

> ->escapeColumns('product_brand_logo')

Answer (score 0):

the best way to show image tag on data table

```
->addColumn('logo_url', function($data) {
   return '<img src="'.$data->logo_url.'" width="95px"/>';
})
```