# How to display image in yajra datatable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

i'm getting only getting path of my image file not image in yajra datatable in laravel..

i already did the steps mentioned on
[how to show image in yajra datatable column , laravel5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629572/how-to-show-image-in-yajra-datatable-column-laravel5-3)

but did not help..

my datatable code

```
editColumn('id_image', function(User $user){
        $url = url("storage/uploads/users/".$user->id. "/".$user->id_image);        
        return '<img src="'. $url .'" />'; 
});
```

it only returns path of my image, it returns like below

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploads/users/38/maruti-suzuki-omni.jpg" />
```

Comment: You have to add `->rawColumns(['id_image'']);` to make it working.

Comment: here is tutorial maybe help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pPvD7xwCq4&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to update the rawColumns with your column name. suppose your column name is vehicle_image then

```
// public function dataTable($query)
->rawColumns(['vehicle_image', 'action']);
```